# pm2 problems: slow and crush

Tags: node.js, pm2

Some problems with pm2.
have latest version of pm2.
After any commands pm2 think about 30-40 seconds.
in processes I see nodejs process that consume CPU and memory by exponent. After reach limit - crush.

win PC. nvm installed.
What is happenned with pm2?

I tried uninstall-install pm2. problem not solved

Comment: now uninstall-install nvm, nodejs - problem not solved/ Nodejs is latest for Win 7 (v14.17.6)